# How to speed up this code?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I have *Mathematica* code for numerically evaluating integrals but it takes hours to run. Is there any way to improve its speed (I am concerned about numerical accuracy, so `MonteCarloRule` is not an option).

Here is the code:

```
Xi[R_, z_, m_, rc_] := rc^m/(rc^m + (R^2 + z^2)^(m/2))

Dz[R_, z_] := (R^2 + z^2)^(1/3);


Df[R_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, 
  rc_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(z1 - z) (Xi[0, z, m, rc] + Xi[R, z, m, rc]), {z, 0,
     z1}] + NIntegrate[(z2 - 
      z) (Xi[0, z, m, rc] + Xi[R, z, m, rc]), {z, 0, z2}] - 
  NIntegrate[(Abs[z2 - z1] - z) Xi[R, z, m, rc], {z, 0, 
    Abs[z2 - z1]}]


DfD[R_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, 
  rc_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Xi[0, z, m, rc], {z, 0, z1}] + 
  NIntegrate[Xi[R, z1 - z, m, rc], {z, 0, z2}]

SDfD[R_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, 
  rc_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Xi[0, z, m, rc] + Xi[R, z2 - z, m, rc], {z, 0, 
    z1}] + NIntegrate[Xi[0, z, m, rc] + Xi[R, z1 - z, m, 
     rc], {z, 0, z2}]

XiI[R_?NumericQ, S_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, 
  rc_?NumericQ, Sigma_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/Sqrt[Dz[R, 
      z1 - z2]] Exp[-(z1 + 
       z2)] Exp[Sigma^2 Df[R, z1, z2, m, 
      rc]] (1 + Sigma^2 Xi[R, z1 - z2, m, 
       rc] - Sigma^2* 
      SDfD[R, z1, z2, m, rc] + Sigma^4 DfD[R, z1, z2, m,
        rc] DfD[R, z2, z1, m, rc]), {z1, 0, S}, {z2, 0, S}]
```

At the end, I need to evaluate the following

```
XiI[0, 0.1, 1/3, 0.001, 0.01] - 
 ParallelTable[XiI[10^R, 0.1, 1/3, 0.001, 0.01], {R, -3, 0, 
   0.1}].
```

Unfortunately, this took about 12 hours to complete. Is there any trick to speed this up without compromising numerical accuracy?

Comment: Have you tried `Parallelize[]`?  By the way:  I strongly suggest you avoid using upper-case-initial names for your variables and functions because they can conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

Comment: In my experience, there usually is more to be gained by improving the algorithm than by optimizing the code.  For instance, if `DfD[R, z1, z2, m, rc]` is a slowly varying function of `z1 and `z2` over `{0, S}`. it may be advantageous to compute an array of values of DfD vs `{z1, z2}` and from it create an `InterpolationFunction` prior to performing the `XiI` integration.

Comment: But the problem is DfD is not only function of `{z1, z2}` but also of `R`.